# Are you able to save the running-config on Nexus Switches

Tags: networking, cisco, switch, cisco-nexus

I have been trolling Cisco sites and have not been able to find an answer to this questions.

Are you able to perform a write mem or likewise to save these configs on Nexus 5000 switches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the handful of Nexus 5K's that I have worked on, `write mem` is not supported.

The only `write` command supported is `write erase`.

Saving the running configuration is achieved with a `copy running-config startup-config`.

NX-OS also adds a little flare to the copy operation with a progress bar...

```
ABC-N5010-01# copy running-config startup-config
[########################################] 100%
ABC-N5010-01#
```

Comment: Thanks mate, copy run start is what I used to use on all switches until I started getting lazy with write mem..

Answer (score 3):

you can also add a line in the config that allows you to use `wr mem` if you wish, or something even shorter. Simply add an alias statement, such as:

`cli alias name wr copy running-config startup-config`